# Is there any other faster method is there to create a image from a raw pixel data in c#?

Tags: c#

At present i am using this code.

```cs
ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.Read(one_sec_RGBbuf, 614400, ref one_sec_No_of_bytes_read);
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(2048, 100, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

int arrayIndex = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 2048; y++)
    {
        pic.SetPixel(y, x, Color.FromArgb(one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex + 2], one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex + 1], one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex]));
        arrayIndex += 3;
    }
}

string p_name = one_count.ToString();
Array.Clear(one_sec_RGBbuf, 0, one_sec_RGBbuf.Length);
pic.Save(p_name + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: The answer is most definitely yes.. Do not use SetPixel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about _code optimisations_ are off-topic. See _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_ and  _[Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help)_ for more information.

Comment: What is the data type of `one_sec_RGBbuf`? Is it an array of ints, or something smaller?

Comment: plz share linek if have @the

Comment: one_sec_RGBbuf it is byte array

Comment: @TheGeneral looks like that's how the supplying device supplies it

Comment: I'm also struck that you could create your own custom stream that reads from your byte array in a custom order and then pass it to Bitmap's constructor

Comment: Try the key word ```Thread```, ```Task```, ```Async``` and ```ActionBlock```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this, which will be magnitudes faster. Note I am a little unsure about your byte array. However this would be enough to get you started.

```
var width = 2048;
var height = 100;

var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
// lock the array for direct access
var data = bmp.LockBits(
   new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
   ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
   PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    
var length = width * height;

try
{

   var span = new Span<int>((int*)data.Scan0, length);

   for (int i = 0, arrayIndex = 0; i < length; i++, arrayIndex += 3)
      span[i] = 0xff << 24 |
                one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex + 2] << 16 |
                one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex + 1] << 8 |
                one_sec_RGBbuf[arrayIndex];     
}
finally
{
   // unlock the bitmap
   bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Disclaimer, this is untested to a large degree.

Also, make sure you dispose your Bitmaps after you finish with them

Comment: var span = new Span<int>((int*)data.Scan0, length); showing error:-
Error CS0214 Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Comment: @sachin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe You will also need to set your build properties to use Unsafe Code as well

Comment: yes that one i changed already.even though showing error

Comment: If you use `data.Scan0.ToPointer()`, does that remove the need for `unsafe`?

Comment: @canton7 unfortunately not , it would be nice though!